# Roll-Up Function with xPath (XML)?

Tags: xml, xpath, salesforce, docusignapi, rollup

I am creating a dynamic table in Microsoft Work to use with Salesforce and DocuSign Gen. In my table I have a column which display a single letter text field. Currently all rows will display a value but I would like that rows with the exact same value (the same letter) should roll-up and only display on the first row with that value and all other rows with that value should be blank in that field. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Sml.png) The image shows how  the rows currently are being displayed and I would like repeating values to be blank.

The syntax I am currently using looks like this: <#  #>

I have tried to find any documentation for such function but with no result.

Comment: Sounds like  you want to group the rows by that letter and only output a value in that column for the first row in each group. Grouping of XML is easy with XSLT or XQuery or LINQ to XML but to do it in XPath alone you kind of need XPath 3.1 and maps.